# Can I preview an open Navigation Drawer in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making an app that will feature a Navigation Drawer. My computer cannot run the AVD emulator. Even with a minimal AVD, I have waited hours and it did not start up. That being said, I have had to rely on the Android Studio designer to see what the app will look like. When creating a Navigation Drawer activity, is there some way I can toggle it being open on the designer?

Comment: Just preview your drawer fragment

Comment: And it will show the overlay over the main view?

Comment: I guess you could also just temporarily change your `DrawerLayout` to a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [See navigation drawer preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368885/see-navigation-drawer-preview)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found that you can add `tools:openDrawer="start"` to your `DrawerLayout`.
Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!-- your content include -->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Demo:

[image]

<sub>not really perfect, but it's enough!</sub>

Comment: somehow it works, thanks. But gives NullPointerException for the line - 'ActionBarDrawerToggle..syncState();' in overrided 'onPostCreate()' method, so I needed remove that  tools:openDrawer="start" line after design complete